# Can I really react positively and negatively to the same job offer?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Yesterday I was looking at some jobs in the website and I decided for the first time react to a job. I clicked in an icon, but after a few seconds I decided to change my reaction. Surprise surprise, the first reaction that I had selected remained.

I'll try to explain with some pictures:

1. First, none of the options is checked

   [image: job reactions without user interaction]
2. If you liked the job offer I suppose you'll mark the thumbs up sign

   [image: job reactions with thumbs up selected]
3. Let's imagine that you changed your mind and checked now the thumbs down sign.

   Now you realize that you can select more than one option at the same time:

   [image: job reactions with thumbs up and thumbs down selected at the same time]
4. Now you realize that you can check all the options at the same time if you want, action which doesn't make sense to me.

   [image]

What are your thoughts about this? Is this a bug?

Comment: Since you can react with a unicorn emoji in the first place, I guess it makes sense nothing makes a lot of sense. It's like the [Chewbaca Defense](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwdba9C2G14) for UI.